# Monotouch: trying to play audio from a file that is generated on the fly using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: c#, streaming, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer

I am facing the following issue..
I want to Record an audio file from Mic using AVAudioRecorder and stream the output to an AVAudioPlayer real time. I tried that by opening a stream

> FileStream f = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

where fileName is the name of the file that the recorder is writing. Then I tryed to initialize an AVAudioPlayer:

> AVAudioPlayer player = AVAudioPlayer.FromData(NSData.FromStream(f));

That always returned a null player, so I wrapped the FileStream to a BufferedStream like

> BufferedStream bf = new BufferedStream(f);

Then I initialized the player using the above line of code, but instead of passing the f stream I passed the bf stream.

That made the player at least to obtain a value other than null, but I couldn't hear anything.

Is there any chance that someone has encountered the same problem, and knows the solution? Can I use AVAudioPlayer that way or am I doing all this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but I am answering in case someone else runs across the question.

To playback the just-recorded audio create the audio player from a URL that is based on the file name you just recorded to:

```
AVAudioPlayer player = AVAudioPlayer.FRomUrl(NSUrl.FromFileName(fileName));
player.PrepareToPlay();
player.Play();
```

Hopefully this helps someone.